# Why do we use (String args[ ]) only in Java?

Tags: java, c++

I was recently asked in an exam why we use main `(String args[ ])` only in java? Why don't we use main `(String args[ ])` in any other programming languages?

Comment: it's in c# as well, not a great exam question :)

Comment: Strange question... And I guess you meant `String[] args`. Anyway, `String[] args` and `String args[]` is the same, though the first form is preferred in Java.

Comment: Yes, an "ars" is something else entirely.

Comment: In C/C+ supports pointers.  Java doesn't support pointers, so doing char[] *args would not be valid.

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact question? Because it appears to be really silly to me. What were you supposed to answer? "Because yes"?

Comment: Because not all language are the same.

Comment: That's sort of like asking "Why do we use the word 'woman' only in English?  Why do other languages use different words?"

Comment: Why do we use #include <stdio.h> only in C?

Comment: C uses `main(int argc, char* argv[])`.  Java doesn't need the separate `argc` paramenter because the `argv` array can be tested to determine it's length.

Comment: If your asking is "Why Java takes String array only in main()", then it's all same in other languages as well since that way user's parameter given during program executing can be passed into main() function. For C, it's like  int main( int argc, const char* argv[] ) instead though...

Comment: Java's `main(String[] args)` on a Mac machine can be written as `main()`. I remember reading this somewhere; can't recall :)

Comment: @LittleChild - There are actually several permitted formats for Java's `main`.

Comment: @HotLicks It's better to fix an _odd typo(?)_ rather than to highlight it.

Comment: @HotLicks Please tell me more :)

Answer (score 5):

`main()` and other ways to shape the entry point into the application is a part of the language. The reason it is done the particular way in particular language is because the author of the language has seen the protocol between the language runtime system (an OS abstraction layer if that language needs to have an OS underneath to run) and the programmer that way.

I can assume that in Java it was made `main(String[] args)` because the language was inspired by `C++` in a way (thus `main()` was preserved) and `String[] args` this is the Java way to pass an array of strings into the function.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding…

> “Why don't we use `main (String ars[])` in any other programming languages?”

That’s a flawed assumption in the question.

C# [example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288463%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
// Hello3.cs
// arguments: A B C D
using System;

public class Hello3
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
      Console.WriteLine("You entered the following {0} command line arguments:",
         args.Length );
      for (int i=0; i < args.Length; i++)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("{0}", args[i]); 
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why don't we use main (String ars[ ]) in any other programming languages?

Because you like to do it probably. If you're asking if you **can** do that in other languages (like C++, with which you marked the topic), the answer is: **yes, you can**.

They syntax for C++ would be:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Or - if you would want to also include environment variables:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
```

Comment: The `envp` argument is a commonly supported but is not part of the C++ standard.

Answer (score 0):

Java has a built in String class so arguments to the class's main method are represented by String args[] or a String array.
 Whereas in C++, there is not built in String class, so arguments are represented by char* argv whereas their count is represented by int argc.

Answer (score 0):

The UNIX interface for invoking an application is to collect the individual command line tokens into an array of strings and pass that array to the entry point of the application.  UNIX defined that this entry point is named "main", and that the command line tokens would be expressed as an array of pointers to C-style null-terminated strings.  Since there's no other way to know the size of the array, the array size was passed as a separate parameter:

```
main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

MSDOS and Windows copied this scheme, so it has become quite standard.

Even though Java programs aren't invoked directly from the operating system, the designers of Java choose to use a similar (familiar) paradigm, where the command line tokens would be passed into a method named "main" as an array of Java String objects.

Comment: I don't remember the MS-DOS scheme, but Windows instead uses a single process *command line*, which each application can parse as it wants. See the `GetCommandLine` API function. There's also a command line parsing function which does a standard parsing.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - It is a little muddled, since there are layers.  It's really a "glue" layer between the OS and the language that does the mapping, I suppose.